# Access mysql-py shell commands from within Python

Tags: python, mysql, nosql

I've never worked with sql/mysql but I've read a bunch of tutorials.
I want to be able to create databases with Python and then conveniently access it using mysql terminal tools.

In Mysql there are relational tables that can be handled by mysql terminal application. In order to access this from python I was able to use python connector.

There are also document store aka nosql databases. To work with this I used mysql-py shell (Chapter 20 of mysql 8.0 manual). However, I cannot access it from within the python, as I didn't find an appropriate module. I understand that there are a bunch of databases created for python, like mongo, but I want to use the original mysql tools.

Is there one? I work on MAC OS.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer :  [X Dev API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html).